# Back Stack fragment blank onbackpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have 2 fragments, when i replace the second fragment and press the back button at that time my first fragment shows blank,here is my code

```
    Fragment fragment = new MovieDetails();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("background", item.getBackg());
            args.putString("thumb", item.getThumb());
            args.putString("id", item.getCode());
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

            boolean fragmentPopped = getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(
                            backStateName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped) { // fragment not in back stack, create it.
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack("TAG");
                ft.commit();
            }
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: When you back press have you identify with your string `"TAG"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this**

```
 private void showFragment() {

    final Myfragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction =
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
    transaction.commit(); 
    }
```

@Override

```
   public void onBackPressed() {
   final Myfragment fragment = (Myfragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);

   if (fragment.allowBackPressed())  {
      super.onBackPressed(); 
   }
```

Comment: try my code that is mention above its works for me. and if useful then accept my answer ok.

Comment: Please format your code again because it is not proper.

Comment: its having showfragment function nd second is overriden method so you  just copy this code if useful.

Comment: Kinjal tu mane to nathi kahi rahi ne kem k aa question me post nathi karyo.

Comment: ya i knw bt ok its edited now may be its clear enough to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't your problem, but it was mine: I'd over-ridden onSaveInstanceState() and forgotten to call through to super. This resulted in a blank fragment after pressing 'back', almost certainly because super.onSaveInstanceState() is where the fragment stack gets saved.